# How to get dirtrack mode working with colored, multi-line prompts

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use the following prompt for my Emacs shell:

```
PS1='\n\[\e[33m\]\w\033[36m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n$ '
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Emacs prompt]

I tried to use the regexp `"(^[^\\(]*)"` to match the path and set it in dirtrack-list:

```
(setq-default dirtrack-list '("(^[^\\(]*)" 1 1))
```

But due to the colors, the shell never matches (so it can't track my cwd). Is it possible to extend my regexp to include the colors?

---

Including @tripleee's regexp works:

```
(setq-default dirtrack-list '("\\s-\\(\033\\[[0-9]+m\\)*\\([^\033\\(]+\\)" 2 1))
```

But now when I `cd` I randomly get the following error in a `*Warnings*` buffer:

```
Warning (emacs):   
/ does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the `rvm` part. When you `cd` in that specific repository, it automatically spits out a line telling you it is using a gemset. The regex is not narrow enough to eliminate this false positive. I believe the following regexp should work: `"\\s-\\(\033\\[[0-9]+m\\)\\([^\033\\(]+\\)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `"^\\(\033\\[[0-9]+m\\)*\\([^\033\\(]+\\)"` and grab the second capture group instead of the first.

Comment: Thanks, this works but now I randomly get:

    `Warning (emacs): Directory
    / does not exist`

In a `*Warnings*` buffer. If I rever the regexp everything works fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in `tracking.el` that throws warnings. I used the following `.emacs` to try and reproduce the problem and got nothing wrong:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
         (lambda ()
           (shell-dirtrack-mode -1)
           (dirtrack-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'dirtrack-directory-change-hook
          (lambda ()
            (message default-directory)))

(setq-default dirtrack-list '("\\s-\\(\033\\[[0-9]+m\\)*\\([^\033\\(]+\\)" 2 1))
```

What OS and what version of emacs are you using?

Comment: I'm using Emacs 23.3.50 (9.0) on Mac OS 10.8.3. I've created a small video that I think best illustrates the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsVXdAM93L8